# What is Binyan HaMalchut?

Tags: midrash, yom-kippur, chabad, chasidut-hasidism, rosh-hashanah-new-year

The Kuntrus Umayan writes, in discourse 18 chapter 1, that the period between Rosh Hashanna and Yom Kippur is for the preparation for Binyan HaMalchut. What does that mean and how does this work? He points to Sefer Halikkutim, Malchut pp 572-4 if anyone has a translation.

Comment: Hello David and welcome to Mi Yodeya. There is an excellent explanation of the process found in Kuntreisim from the Mitteler Rebbe. Like he usually does, it is a detailed explanation of the entire transition. If you haven't learned it, it is well with the effort.

Answer (score 1):

The Sefer HaLikkutim on malchus begins [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=58832&st=&pgnum=544&hilite=).

However, in the edition linked, it makes mention of Binyan HaMalchus on this page [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=58832&st=&pgnum=531&hilite=) - (4 lines down)

It writes there:

> **בכל ר"ה צ"ל התחדשות בחי' מלכות ית' בנין המלכות**. פי' שיתחדש האור והמחשבה ממקור בחי' המל' והוא בחי' כתר עליון ורצון עליון שיאיר ויתלבש א"ס ב"ה הסוכ"ע בבחי' ע"ס דמל'
>
> With every Rosh Hashanah there needs to be a sense of renewal in the concept of Kingship may it be blessed - a binyan hamalchus - a construction of kingship. Meaning that light and thought will be renewed from the source of the kingship and it is this concept of a supreme crown and a supreme desire that will illuminate and clothe without measure, encircling all worlds with a sense of infinite kingship.

The Chabad website [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3082/jewish/The-Waking-of-Creation.htm) helps to explain it further:

> On the eve of Rosh Hashanah, all things revert to their primordial state. The Inner Will ascends and is retracted into the divine essence; the worlds are in a state of sleep and are sustained only by the Outer Will. The service of man on Rosh Hashanah is to rebuild the divine attribute of sovereignty and reawaken the divine desire, "I shall reign," with the sounding of the shofar.

It is an essential cornerstone of Chassidus, and it explains it [here](https://insidechassidus.org/class-one-10/#) that G-d created the world and made it conditional for the Jews to make Him as it were value you. This world therefore is only valuable to Hashem if we elevate it by doing mitzvos and keeping his Torah. On Rosh Hashanah we make a pointing of crowning G-d as king.

Answer (score 1):

Asides from what Dov writes, [see](https://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA):

> האריז"ל גילה שבכל שנה כאשר מסתיימת השנה מסתלקת החיות האלוקית מהעולמות, והיא חוזרת ונכללת במקורה, וכדי להמשיך אותה מחדש, צריך לעורר בקב"ה מחדש את הרצון לחזור ולמלוך על העולמות. כיון ששורש ההשפעה של האור האלוקי לרדת בפועל ולהימשך לעולמות הוא בספירת המלכות, שמצד עצמה אין לה כל תכלית מלבד המשכת האלוקות בעולמות, מכונה הדבר בשם 'בנין המלכות', כי כאשר בני ישראל מצליחים לעורר את הרצון במלוכה, הם מחדשים את פעולתה של ספירת המלכות[1](https://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA).
>
> הסבר זה מבוסס על לשון הפסוק: ""ארץ אשר ה' אלקיך דורש אותה, תמיד עיני
> ה' אלקיך בה, מרשית השנה ועד אחרית שנה"[2](https://www.theyeshiva.net/jewish/2532/maamar-zeh-hayom-5741-2-defining-malchus), שאף שהקב"ה דורש את ארץ
> ישראל תמיד, בכל זאת הפסוק מכנה זאת בלשון 'מראשית השנה ועד אחרית שנה',
> כיון שבאחרית כל שנה החיות מסתלקת, ועם ראשית השנה, באמצעות עבודתם של
> בני ישראל בראש השנה - הם פועלים את 'בנין המלכות'.
>
> במשך הזמן שבין סיום השנה להתחדשות בנין המלכות בתקיעת שופר של בוקר ראש
> השנה, משול המצב בעולם לאדם שהלך לישון ועיקר החיות שלו הסתלקה, וכל
> החיות של הגוף היא בבחינת קיסטא דחיותא, והגוף ממשיך להתקיים מחיצוניות
> החיות שהותירה הנשמה בגוף, ולכן זהו מצב מאויים, בו הקב"ה מנהיג את העולם
> בחיצוניות אך בלי עונג ורצון פנימי. גם עובדה זו נרמזת בפסוק במילה
> "תמיד", שלמרות שיש זמן שבו יש הפסק לצורך חידוש המלוכה, עדיין באופן
> חיצוני המלוכה ממשיכה באופן רציף ותמידי.
>
> עבודה זו נרמזת בנוסח תפילת מוסף של ראש השנה "זה היום תחילת מעשיך זכרון
> ליום ראשון", שכפי שבתחילת מעשה בראשית היה צריך את עבודתו של האדם שיאמר
> "בואו נשתחוה ונכרעה נברכה לפני ה' עושנו" ובכך ימשיך את החיות בעולמות,
> כך גם בכל שנה מחדש צריך להמשיך זאת.

My own loose interpretation of this, is that at the end of the year, our own animal soul moves away temporarly, so we are able to "build the Kingdom", e.g. infuse holinesss and spirituality into our lives. This happens during the last weeks of the Jewish Year, during Yom Kippur and Rosh Hashanah.

See:

> עבודה זו נרמזת בנוסח תפילת מוסף של ראש השנה "זה היום תחילת מעשיך זכרון ליום ראשון", שכפי שבתחילת מעשה בראשית היה צריך את עבודתו של האדם שיאמר "בואו נשתחוה ונכרעה נברכה לפני ה' עושנו" ובכך ימשיך את החיות בעולמות, כך גם בכל שנה מחדש צריך להמשיך זאת.

[See also this lesson, including source sheet](https://www.theyeshiva.net/jewish/2532/maamar-zeh-hayom-5741-2-defining-malchus) from TheYeshiva.net.

What is the concept of Binyan HaMalchus about? Well, it is all about (re)building Hashems Kingdom on earth. How do we do that?

> התעוררות הרצון של המלך למלוך הוא על ידי שהעם מתבטלים אליו ומקבלים את מלכותו בקבלת עול.
> The awakening of the king's desire to reign is by the people surrendering to him and accepting his kingdom by accepting a yoke.

The actual building of the kingdom is done on Rosh Hashanah. However, the building of the kingdom is a continuous process. It is a process that goes on during the ten days of Teshuvah:

> בשל כך, גם לאחר שהסתיימה בראש השנה עצם העבודה של בנין המלכות, יש להמשיך ולפעול את שלימות בנין המלכות שתרד למטה בפועל בריבוי חילוקים וצמצומים. דבר זה נעשה על ידי העבודה של עשרת ימי תשובה, ואמירת מזמור 'שיר המעלות ממעמקים', דבר הרמוז בכך ש'עומק' הוא בגימטריא 216, אותה הגימטריא של המילה גבורה, ועל ידי שאומרים עשר פעמים מזמור זה, ממשיכים את כל עשר ה'עומקים' ועם גבורות אלו יכול להיות קיום עשר הספירות[9].

Answer (score 1):

Hi David welcome to Mi Yodeya, looking forward to seeing your contributions, starting with this great question.

Dov and Shmuel have given the right answer, I just want to add a plain language explanation, based off of shiurim by Rav Manis Friedman, a big baal chassidus. For example, see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZJQvoROhz_s).

The tzaddikim teach us that being King of the world isn't all about Hashem's Glory. In fact, being King of a finite world, taking care of the needs of the people, is actually beneath Hashem. In His great humility, He wants to do it. Why? It's always the same answer: Bishvil Yisrael nivra olam. We are who He does it for, we are His people, the apple of His Eye, His Ta'anug in being King (His inner will, as mentioned by Dov). So will He be crowned this year into a "chore" of ruling a world that doesn't recognise or care about Him (which is covered by His outer will), or will it be His Simcha and a pleasure to be crowned King by His beloved people? I.e. you and me.